Can I reallocate space on /boot and / remotely?
I have a very old, dedicated coloc server 1500 miles away. My /boot partition is far too small.
$ df -h /boot /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        88M   56M   26M  69% /boot
/dev/sda3        72G   58G   10G  86% /

A single kernel is installed, and yet I'm out of space for apt:
$ sudo du -sh /boot/*
187K   /boot/config-4.4.0-170-generic
6.7M   /boot/grub
36M    /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-170-generic
12K    /boot/lost+found
179K   /boot/memtest86+.bin
181K   /boot/memtest86+.elf
181K   /boot/memtest86+_multiboot.bin
3.8M   /boot/System.map-4.4.0-170-generic
6.9M   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-170-generic

$ sudo apt --purge autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 63 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.16) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (1.157.23) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-170-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1

I'd be happy to hand a few more hundred MB from / over to /boot. However, the answers I see online all involve booting from a live USB and running gparted. I can't do that over ssh. Is there any way to solve my out-of-space problem without physical access to the machine? Is there a way to lean down the kernel?
In case it matters, currently running Ubuntu 16 :/

This version is long past eol and off topic on this site so it does matter. You can post this question on unix.stackexchange.com

There is no reliable way to solve the problem without physical access to the machine. Any remote method you discover will risk your system becoming unbootable.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's standard support life thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  This is community support; 16.04 is EOSS thus out of community support.

Some enterprise geared hardware allows you to access the device remotely for everything, using the machines iLO/iDRAC/etc functionality  so even a stuck machine (with no OS running) can be dealt with remotely; but those features are done by the hardware itself as the OS isn't yet running.  Any Ubuntu release from 2016 is now EOSS or EOL.
